# Returning a column with grep

Tags: search, awk, grep, cut

I'm attempting to search through a file and return a particular column based on whether a particular value is present in the column. For example, if I search for "Red" in the file:

```
One    Two    Three
Cat    Dog    Chicken
Blue   Black  Red
Blah   Blah   Blah
```

I want returned:

```
Three
Chicken
Red
Blah
```

I would even accept just knowing which column grep or any other search command found a match in, so I could use cut, but I can't even find that much.

Comment: You could try using color option, which can highlight the particular word, which can I help identify column. grep "string" --color

Comment: What if the string you're looking for appeared in multiple columns - do you want all matching columns printed or the first one o something else? Do you want an RE match so `Re.*` matches `Red` and `Refer` or a strict string comparison? Do you want to match on partial words so `Red` would match `Reds` or `Redder`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I'm trying to find all columns that have a complete match.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

Store all the data in the matrix `a[line][column]`. Save the column number in `p`. Finally print all the items `a[line][p]`.

```
$ awk -v text=Blue '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i]=$i; if ($i~text) {p=i}}} END{ for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i,p]}' a
One
Cat
Blue
Blah
$ awk -v text=Red '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i]=$i; if ($i~text) {p=i}}} END{ for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i,p]}' a
Three
Chicken
Red
Blah
```

#### Update

To have exact matches, replace `~` with `==` ([thanks konsolebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707788/returning-a-column-with-grep/18707918#comment27565754_18707918)):

```
awk -v text=Blue '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i]=$i; if ($i==text) {p=i}}} END{ for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i,p]}' a
                                                            ^^
```

Comment: +1 for the clean solution. `==` can be used too instead of `~` to have exact matches even with regex characters.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, depending on how you respond to the questions I posted in my comment:

```
awk -v tgt="Red" '
  NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==tgt) cols[i]; next}
  {sep=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i in cols) {printf "%s%s", sep, $i; sep=OFS}; print ""}
' file file
```